# How to groupby an index as well as a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Let's say I have a simple dataframe which has an index of a datetime and three columns - one being a value and one being an aggregating indicator and the last being a unique identifier. The index is not unique across the dataframe, as it is duplicated over multiple instances of the indicator. ie it looks like this:

```
index, val, aggregating indicator, unique_ref
1-Jan, 1, set_a,r1
2-Jan, 2, set_a,r2
1-Jan, 3, set_a,r3
2-Jan, 4, set_a,r4
1-Jan, 5, set_b,r5
2-Jan, 6, set_b,r6
```

Is it possible to aggregate (in one step) the val and group by the index as well as the aggregating_indicator ?

ie the result I would like is

```
index, sum, aggregating_indicator
1-Jan, 4, set_a // ie 1+3
2-Jan, 6, set_a // ie 2+4
1-Jan, 5, set_b
2-Jan, 6, set_b
```

Doing it in two steps is ok... But I was wondering if it was possible to do it in one neat way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby(['index','aggregating indicator'])['val'].sum().reset_index()
   index aggregating indicator  val
0  1-Jan                 set_a    4
1  1-Jan                 set_b    5
2  2-Jan                 set_a    6
3  2-Jan                 set_b    6
```

Comment: great so far.. The index does not have a name though - sorry for not making that clear in the question. Oops scratch that. Works fine! Will accept answer in 3 mins (when it allows)